# How to limit results retrurned by MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code and it works great. The only issue is that I will get multiple results at once and I just need the one. Lets say I am looking for account # 2, if I type two into the input box name="id" , I will get all results that have the number 2..
If I want to look for a specific person's name, and I type first name and then I enter another last name.. it will bring the first name I want but it will bring other results with the last name I entered. How can I set a limit on the results I look for so either I get a match or not? I am still learning. thank you

PS. valid to say, no where I can specify LIMIT 1..

```
$searchFields = []; 

foreach (['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'] as $searchField) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$searchField])) {

        $searchFields[$searchField] = $_POST[$searchField];
    }
}


if (count($searchFields) > 0) {
    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `Demo_Guests` WHERE 0";
    foreach (array_keys($searchFields) as $fieldName) {
        $queryStr .= " OR " . $fieldName . " LIKE :" . $fieldName ;
    }
    //var_dump($queryStr);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($queryStr);
    foreach($searchFields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
        $stmt->bindValue(':'. $fieldName, "%$fieldValue%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //var_dump($result);
} else {
    echo  "";
}

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: There's no `try` for the `catch` at the end.

Comment: There is.. I just posted the part of the code I need to resolve.. it's all there.. my issue is just the query itself .  Thanks

Comment: If the `try` isn't relevant, then don't post the `catch`. It's confusing when you post code with mismatched brackets, it's hard to tell what the real code might be.

Comment: You do have a point there.. didn't even think about it.. got.it for next time.. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of `$queryStr`.

```
$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `Demo_Guests` WHERE 0";
foreach (array_keys($searchFields) as $fieldName) {
    $queryStr .= " OR " . $fieldName . " LIKE :" . $fieldName ;
}
$queryStr .= " LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: this was exactly what I wanted!!! I don't even know why I did not think about this.. I did try to add the " LIMIT 1 "  but to the first $queryStr.. after the last $fieldName.. why wouldn't it work there? I don't get that.

Comment: Because then your query looks like `WHERE fieldname1 = :fieldname1 LIMIT 1 OR fieldname2 = :fieldname2 LIMIT 1`. You can't mix `LIMIT` inside the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: still learning Barmar... lol I am studying every day .. thank you.!